# How to redirect to a new page when user is logged in Firebase?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-hooks, firebase-authentication, google-oauth

please I am working on a project with Firebase authentication. The sign in functionality works perfectly. However I want to redirect the current login page to another page when user is logged in and back to the login page when user is logged out.

Comment: are you using any routing library ? say react router dom for e.g. ?

Comment: Yes I am. I am using react-router-dom

Comment: you can check [redirect](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/fetch/redirect) ..

Comment: That sounds promising indeed KcH, especially when you use it in response to Firebase's `onAuthStateChanged` event instead of a `getUser` call as shown in the first code snippet in the Firebase documentation on [getting the current user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I am using the onAuthStateChanged and I tried using the redirect but it doesn't seem to work. I am probably doing something wrong. How do you think I can do it?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the [minimal code with which any of us can reproduce where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).